# Reading image from excel and storing it in sqlserver

Tags: java, excel, sql-server-2008

I have a table called 'tab1'

```
cl_id int //auto imcrement
cl_image image
```

i want to read a image from excel with image and store it in the above table

```
FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(
            "Delux.xls");
    System.out.println(fileInputStream);
    HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(fileInputStream);
    HSSFSheet worksheet = workbook.getSheet("Delux");
    Iterator rows = worksheet.rowIterator();
    HSSFRow row = (HSSFRow) rows.next();
      List lst = workbook.getAllPictures();
      Iterator it = lst.iterator();
    while (rows.hasNext()) {
        row = (HSSFRow) rows.next();

//reading the image from excel

        HSSFCell cellP1 = row.getCell((short) 1);
           PictureData pict = (PictureData)it.next();
            String ext = pict.suggestFileExtension();
            byte[] data = pict.getData();

                InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(data);

        try {

            PreparedStatement stmt = getdbconn()
                    .prepareStatement(
                            "insert into tab1 (cl_image) values(?)");

            stmt.setBinaryStream(1, is);
            stmt.executeUpdate();
            is.close();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SQLException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

but when i store the image dynamically i getting the error like

> "String or binary data would be truncated".

Can anyone suggest me a method to achieve this???

Comment: Have you tried using a `PreparedStatement.setBinaryStream` method which gives the length? `stmt.setBinaryStream(1, is, data.length);`

Comment: yeah i tried but it does not work

Comment: How big is `data.length`?

Comment: it varies for different image like 140,200 etc

Comment: Sure it varies. How big is it, if the error occurs? If it is really not as big, make sure, your field data type of `cl_image` is really `image`. Or try `varbinary(max)`.

Comment: @Axel Richter, I tried using both Image and varbinary(max) but some image gets inserted others images get the above error

Answer (score 0):

Data Types like IMAGE and TEXT not going to be supported and they are deprecated.
So Change it to VARBINARY(max).Most import thing is taht IMAGE data type requires storing the size in a special way rather than expanding VARBINARY to cater for anything all the way to 2GB. The error you get was raised becasue image not fit in cl_image field.